# Automatically increment selected row through DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update a selected row to a number and increment every other row after that by 1 from the newly updated value, leaving all previous rows unaffected

I have the selected row to update figured out:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

     Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

     With DataGridView1
         .Rows(i).Cells("Value").Value = NumTextbox.Text
     End With
```

I tried adding:

```
         .Rows(i).Cells("Value").Value = i + 1
```

But only labels the value to the number of the row, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are trying to increase the value in the other rows after the selected one, you would need a loop.

Comment: @LarsTech yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do but not 100% sure how to implement the loop

Comment: `For j As Integer = i + 1 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: @LarsTech still not quite grabbing the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it all together...

```
Private Sub IncrementRows()
        Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim num As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(NumTextbox.Text, num) Then
            With DataGridView1
                .Rows(i).Cells("Value").Value = num
            End With
            For j As Integer = i + 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                num += 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Value").Value = num
            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
            NumTextbox.Focus
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Mary tried your solution, it updates the current cell, increments the next cell, but all the cells after that don't increment any more than 1. Example - Update it to 4, all cells after that come up as 5, when I'd like it 4, 5, 6, 7 etc. Know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Very sorry, code error on incrementing num. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
For j As Integer = i + 1 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 
DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Value").Value = i + 1
next
```

Comment: This has managed to update all rows after the one selected, but it retrieves the row number rather than the value of that cell. It's getting closer, the value of the cell represents as "NumTextbox"

Comment: Try putting index of cell : DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(PUT_INDEX_HERE).Value